# How to stop old calls on repetitive function calls

Tags: angular

I am using search input to search from server on every letter input. But i do not know how to stop old calls. When i type word with 6 letters the list updates 6 times in a row after seconds. How can i stop old calls on new call?

Input in html

```
<input class="form-control form-control-rounded" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="searchBody.searchString" (ngModelChange)="searchChanged()">
```

Function trigging from input:

```
 async searchChanged() {

    this.spinner.show('mainSpinner');

    await this.getOrders(this.searchBody);

    this.spinner.hide('mainSpinner');

 }
```

Function trigging from searchChanged()

```
async getOrders(body) {

    let response: any = await this.orderService.getOrders(body);

    this.totalOrders = response[0].pagingData.totalCount;

    this.orders = response[0].data;

}
```

Function in orderService

```
async getOrders(body: any) {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }

    const url = this.baseURL;

    let promise = await this.httpClient.post(url , body, httpOptions).toPromise();

    let response = await Promise.all([promise]);

    return response;

  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For this type of research you can think of using web sockets instead of sending an http request for every letter

Comment: Thank you, i will research it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this neatly with promises. This is where `Observables` come so much in handy. For instance with using the `switchMap` you can cancel previous requests when a new requests comes along, and with the `debounceTime` operator, you can control a certain debounce on your requests.

This also requires the use of the `async` pipe for neatness. The best thing would be to also make your `totalOrders` and `orders` observables, so you don't need to `subscribe` inside the component and thus, also unsubscribe on destroy.

I see no template code for these two variables, so I'll just show you an example on how to do it just with the search variable:

<sub>Removing unnecessary things for simplicity sake</sub>

```
<input [ngModel]="searchString$ | async" (ngModelChange)="searchString$.next($event)">
```

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnDestroy {
  readonly searchString$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  private readonly searchSub: Subscription = this.searchString$.pipe(
    tap(() => this.spinner.show('mainSpinner')),
    debounceTime(200),
    switchMap((search) => this.getOrders(search)),
    tap(() => this.spinner.hide('mainSpinner'))
  ).subscribe()

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.searchSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  private getOrders(search: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.orderService.getOrders({
      ...this.searchBody,
      searchString: search
    }).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.totalOrders = response.pagingData.totalCount;
        this.orders = response.data;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

```
export class OrderService {
  getOrders(body: any): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }

    const url = this.baseURL;

    return this.httpClient.post(url, body, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

The `switchMap` will make sure that the previous http request will get canceled. There is also a `debounceTime` of 200, which will make sure that if you keep typing, nothing will be requested until the user stops typing for 200ms. It will drastically reduce the amount of (unnecessary) requests to your server.

---

**Alternative solution**

The `subscribe/unsubscribe` pattern is something I dislike, and the angular team actually has that pretty nifty `async` pipe which takes care of all these things. So you can even simplify your code more by utilizing this. I'll give some example code:

Consider this to be your HTML:

```
<input [ngModel]="searchString$ | async (ngModelChange)="searchString$.next($event)">

<div *ngFor="let order of orders$ | async; trackBy: trackByOrder"></div>
<div>Total orders: {{ totalOrders$ | async}}</div>
```

You can update your component like this:

```
export class SearchComponent {
  readonly searchString$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  readonly orderReponse$ = this.searchString$.pipe(
    tap(() => this.spinner.show('mainSpinner')),
    debounceTime(200),
    switchMap((search) => this.orderService.getOrders({
      ...this.searchBody,
      searchString: search
    })),
    tap(() => this.spinner.hide('mainSpinner')),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
  );

  readonly orders$ = this.orderReponse$.pipe(
    map(({ data }) => data)
  );

  readonly totalOrders$ = this.orderReponse$.pipe(
    map(({ pagingData }) => pagingData.totalCount) 
  );

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {}

  trackByOrder(idx: number, order: any): string {
    // very important for performance sake. Return a unique order id
  }
}
```

**note:** if you want the search to start on component initialization and not when a user types, you should change the `ReplaySubject<string>(1)` to a `BehaviorSubject<string>('')`

Comment: Thank you, for your long answer. I will try it tomorrow and inform you. Not now because its the end of work.

Comment: I tried it, working good when i do 
`this.searchString$.next('C');
  this.searchString$.next('Ce');
 this.searchString$.next('Cen');` in ngOnInit().
But there is an error in html input: "ctx.searchString$.next is not a function"
And spinners are not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Okay, it is working perfect now. Edited html like this: `<input [(ngModel)]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="searchString$.next(searchString)">` Also spinners are working too now, but i don't know why. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Searches usually need a timeout to account for the time the user is pressing keys before sending the actual request, this usually falls under 150 to 200ms.

I would suggest:

1. creating a global timeout variable
2. clear the timeout variable when there is a change in the search input
3. send the search request after a few seconds has lapsed.

translating this to code, your searchChanged() function would look something like below:

```
var searchRequestTimeout;
async searchChanged() {
    this.spinner.show('mainSpinner');
    clearTimeout(this.searchRequestTimeout); 
    this.searchRequestTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        await this.getOrders(this.searchBody);
        this.spinner.hide('mainSpinner');
    }, 150);
 }
```

This would ensure that a request is never sent while the user is still typing.

Comment: What if the user is a slow typer :)?

Comment: @Poul Kruijt if the user is a slow typer then the search will be sent :D but the guarantee here is that the request doesnt get sent multiple times in a short amount of time, ensuring that only one request is sent at a time.

Comment: Thank you, but that is last thing i want to do.

Comment: @Yagiz Turkmen, okay did you try my answer on your code? It is only 4 lines of modification.

Comment: Yes, i did. It sent 3 calls on normal speed typing. It can be less with higher time for timeout but i can not trust it. Thank you anyway.